# Creating loop iteration using Array and create zip file

Tags: bash

Trying to create zip file based on the directories, to initiate process declared as current directory based on dirs command. Then based on the dirs assigned the directory into array format. Using for loop (sub_dir) get the input data from dirs[@] as list and it will print the file name before creating zip file.

I don't see any error message while running the script but I'm not getting any zip file after the script completion.

Directory structure

```
└─# tree
.
├── Inbound
│   └── Lambda
│       ├── app-inbound
│       │   ├── outbound-primary.py
│       │   └── requirements.txt
│       └── app-outbound
│           ├── inbound-primary.py
│           └── requirements.txt
```

```
#!/bin/bash
start_dir=/tmp/Inbound
echo "start_dir=$start_dir"

for d in "$start_dir"/*/ ; do
   cd "$d" || exit
   dirs=(*/)
   declare -p dirs
   echo "Entring into location"
   for sub_dir in "${dirs[@]}"
   do
     echo "$sub_dir"
     zip "$sub_dir".zip "$sub_dir"
   done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
zip "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"
```

Because if you put debug mode with `bash -x`, you will see:

```
+ zip app-inbound/.zip app-inbound/
```

It's a *parameter expansion* to delete trailing `/`.

See [parameter expansion](https://web.archive.org/web/20230301181506/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: Yes now i can able to make zip file but inside the zip i don't see any files based on the sub-directory. └─# zip -sf  app-inbound.zip
Archive contains:
  app-inbound/
Total 1 entries (0 bytes)

Comment: Thanks lot for your help, option -r working making zip  zip -r "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"